# Delete child nodes after a certain child node

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I want to remove all the nodes (including text) inside an element that are below an `<hr/>` element (including the `<hr/>`).

For example, this:

```
<td class="one">
    Some text
    <a href="page1.html"/>
    <br/>
    Some more text
    <br/>
    <a href="page2.html"/>
    <hr/>
    Bottom text
    <br/>
    <a href="page3.html"/>
</td>
```

Should become:

```
<td class="one">
    Some text
    <a href="page1.html"/>
    <br/>
    Some more text
    <br/>
    <a href="page2.html"/>
</td>
```

I have this XPath to find all the elements below `<hr/>`:

```
./node()[ preceding-sibling::hr[not(following-sibling::hr)] ]
```

But I don't know how to delete these elements.
I tried to do it this way:

```
xp = './node()[ preceding-sibling::hr[not(following-sibling::hr)] ]'
els = self.xpath(xp, td_el)
for el in els:
    el.getparent().remove(el)
```

But it doesn't work for text nodes.

What's the best way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use below code to remove nodes:

```
from lxml import etree, html

source = """<td class="one">
    Some text
    <a href="page1.html"/>
    <br/>
    Some more text
    <br/>
    <a href="page2.html"/>
    <hr/>
    Bottom text
    <br/>
    <a href="page3.html"/>
</td>"""
html = html.fromstring(source)
parent = html.xpath('//td')[0]
redundant = html.xpath('//hr/preceding-sibling::*[1]/following-sibling::*')

for node in redundant:
    parent.remove(node)

print(etree.tostring(parent))
```

Output

```
<td class="one">
    Some text
    <a href="page1.html"/>
    <br/>
    Some more text
    <br/>
    <a href="page2.html"/>
</td>
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But It's not clear to me why the text is removed with the nodes here (which is what I need, of course). The `redundant` list doesn't contain the text nodes.

Comment: @user10540755 this is due to specifics of `lxml`: `lxml` doesn't recognize text nodes as `Element` objects, but as simple strings. So when you do `html.xpath('//*')` you get list of `Element` objects only. If you do `html.xpath('//text()')` - you get list of text nodes (strings)